# Decode application/x-www-form-urlencoded type requests in python3

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest, odoo

I'm working with a form which sends data to a python http route.The data is on "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" format.
I'm getting the data in python somewhat like below

```
{'------WebKitFormBoundarypuLc9h7o7mqJXW4f\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"number_of_users"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarypuLc9h7o7mqJXW4f\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="company_name"\r\n\r\n1234\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarypuLc9h7o7mqJXW4f\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_phone"\r\n\r\n8709310505\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarypuLc9h7o7mqJXW4f\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="contact_email"\r\n\r\nazure.Interior24@example.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarypuLc9h7o7mqJXW4f--\r\n'}
```

I'm unable to decode this.Please help me to convert this to a dict or json.

the data is send from JavaScript like

```
xhttp.open("POST", "/subscribe/checkout", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('number_of_users', no_o_users);
formData.append('company_name', company_name);
formData.append('contact_phone', contact_phone);
formData.append('contact_email', contact_email);
xhttp.send(formData);
```

The python goes like below

```
from odoo.http import request
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class SubscriptionPage(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/subscribe/checkout', type='http', method=['GET', 'POST'], auth='public', website=True, csrf=False)
    def submit_checkout(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        return request.redirect('/shop/cart')
```

Comment: You need to tell us what your "python http route" is. How does it work? Are you using some kind of framework? Show the code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, I'm working on odoo framework, I will edit the question to add more code

Comment: Given that you appear to control both sides of this, why send as form-encoded at all? Why not send JSON?

Comment: @DanielRoseman because the 'request.redirect()' method will not be working if we use 'json'

Comment: What? Why not? What does one have to do with the other?

Comment: No. But this has nothing to do with any of that. You can't redirect, presumably, because you are sending your request via Ajax. Sending the content of that request as form-encoded data won't change the way the browser interacts with the response.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The controller is not redirected to the specific root when the form encoded is JSON. I just want to figure out whether I convert this form encoded data to python dict or json

Comment: As I said, the redirection has **nothing at all** to do with how the form data is encoded.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In my case, it changes the request type, I don't know why